# JQuery Live and Sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, live, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to implement drag and drop so I can sort lists of data and update the database with the relevant positions.

I have a working example but when I try to use the same code on lists that are brought in via ajax the event is binding but none of its methods are triggered and the items do not stay swapped, (They swap back when you let go of the mouse)

here is my html

```
<ul class='sortable'>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>Data</li>
            <li>Data2</li>
        </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
        <ul>
            <li>Data3</li>
            <li>Data4</li>
        </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

and then my JavaScript looks like this. I only want the internal UL's to be swapped. Ie the lists containing the li Data2 etc.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //$(".sortable").disableSelection();
    $(".sortable").live("dblclick", function()
    {
        $(".sortable").sortable({
            update : function()
            {
                alert("update");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Using an event like double click or click was the only way I could get the event to bind at all. Using sortable did not work.

Here is the code I have used to tried to bind the element as well as the sample above

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".sortable").live("sortable", function()
    {
        $(".sortable").sortable({
            update : function()
            {
                alert("update");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I also tried the above code without the .live() wrapped around but that did not work either.

Here is the code that loads the list from the server,

```
$(".myLink").live("click", function()
{
    var id   = $(this).attr("id");
    var url = base_url + "admin/controller/function/" + id;

    showList(url);

    return false;
});


//loads data into the form div
function showList(url)
{
    var arr = new Array();
    $.post(url, arr, function(data)
    {
        $("#form").html(data);

    }, "text");
}
```

Any suggestions or pointers in the right direction would help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have managed to fix it and I am unsure why this would stop it working but it definitely is the problem. The List I was trying to sort had a float left in the style sheet on it for displaying the list horizontally. Once I removed this style the update event was then triggered.

I now just use display:inline to to style the list horizontally. I hope this helps somebody because it's took my hours to work it out.

Thanks for the help.
Ben

Answer (score 2):

**[update]**

Change your AJAX callback line from `$("#form").html(data);` to this:

```
$("#form").html(data).find('.sortable').sortable(originalOptions);
```

And change your original `sortable()` command (which I am assuming is elsewhere) to something like this:

```
var originalOptions = { update: function(){ alert('click');}  };
$(".sortable").sortable( originalOptions );
```

The important thing is making sure `originalOptions` is available for use in your `showList` function.

**[original answer]**

You just need to use `refresh` when the list is updated. So lets say you have this `$.post` code:

```
$.post('/url', { new_positions: whatever }, function(data){
  // data = a bunch of 'lis' but no 'ul'
  $('.sortable').html(data).sortable('refresh');
}, 'html');
```

This changes out the old `li` items for the new ones, and the `refresh` should rebind and accept the new items.

Comment: The list is not been updated it is actually been added to the page and I am unable to bind the sortable to it other than using a click event as stated above. But the update function is never triggered when the user drag and drops.

Comment: @Ben, please update your question to include the code you tried to bind the element including the code for dynamically adding the new element to the page. Chances are the problem lies there.

Comment: updated my question. Any more questions just let me know. Thanks

Comment: @Doug, Thanks for the help. I have changed the code to how you said and It works the same to how I have it now. The update event is never triggered and the list items switch back when i release the click.

Comment: Can anyone else offer some suggestions for this? I'm working to a deadline and I still have not managed to figure this out. I can pay someone if you feel you could solve the problem if you had a closer look at the site.

Comment: Why don't you try to destroy it, and instantiate it again?
**Edit:**

Yes, I just tried it and it does work if you just destroy and instantiate it again after updating the element.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see you managed to fix it. Ignore my previous comment (: